# How to generate a page for a mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently able to insert a row in my *viewjobs.php* page every time a form has been submitted. However, is it possible for me to generate a new page every time? For example *job?=$id*. The main reason I would like to do this is so I'm able to print a job sheet off.

**viewjobs.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, model, jobdesc, paid, price, phone, address, postcode, password, notes, status, datebooked FROM jobs";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover '>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><center>ID</center></th>
      <th><center>Name</center></th>
      <th><center>Model</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Job Description</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Paid</center></th>
      <th><center>Price Paid</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Phone Number</center></th>
      <th><center>Address</center></th>
      <th><center>Postcode</center></th>
      <th><center>Password</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Additional Notes</center></th>
      <th><center>Status</center></th>
      <th width='70%'><center>Date Added</center></th>
      <th width='70%'><center>Options</center></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>"; echo  $row["id"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["name"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["model"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["jobdesc"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["paid"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["price"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["phone"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["address"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["postcode"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["password"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["notes"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["status"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["datebooked"]. "</td>
      <td><a href='#' class='btn btn-sq-xs btn-warning'><i class='fa fa-print fa-1x'></i><br/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
```

**Jobs.php**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$jobdesc = $_POST['jobdesc'];
$paid = $_POST['paid'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$datebooked = date("Y/m/d");

$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (name, model, jobdesc, paid, price, phone, address, postcode, password, notes, datebooked)
VALUES ('$name', '$model', '$jobdesc', '$paid', '$price', '$phone', '$address', '$postcode', '$password', '$notes',$datebooked)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://localhost/services/viewjobs.php' />";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

?>
```

Comment: one question: do you want a php page which displays a single db table row extracted by id, or do you want a page listing your entire db table?

Comment: Just a single db table row that will be extracted by id. I'm able to print the entire db table via phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Get a parameter form the querystring ("id" in this example), add a WHERE statement to your previous sql code, and this will print a single row.

call it in your browser like this: http://yoursite/thispage.php?id=XX (xx= the id of the record you want to display)

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if (!is_numeric($id) || $id<0) { die("BAD ID!"); } // THIS AVOIDS INJECTIONS

$sql = "SELECT id, name, model, jobdesc, paid, price, phone, address,"
     ." postcode, password, notes, status, datebooked FROM jobs"
     ." WHERE id=" . $id;

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of a single row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover '>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><center>ID</center></th>
      <th><center>Name</center></th>
      <th><center>Model</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Job Description</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Paid</center></th>
      <th><center>Price Paid</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Phone Number</center></th>
      <th><center>Address</center></th>
      <th><center>Postcode</center></th>
      <th><center>Password</center></th>
      <th width='30%'><center>Additional Notes</center></th>
      <th><center>Status</center></th>
      <th width='70%'><center>Date Added</center></th>
      <th width='70%'><center>Options</center></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>"; echo  $row["id"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["name"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["model"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["jobdesc"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["paid"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["price"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["phone"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["address"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["postcode"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["password"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["notes"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["status"]. "</td>
      <td>"; echo  $row["datebooked"]. "</td>
      <td><a href='#' class='btn btn-sq-xs btn-warning'><i class='fa fa-print fa-1x'></i><br/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Could I possible do it so I can run that code on a different page with a different layout?

Comment: sure, the WHERE clause can be used in any SQL query.

Comment: Ah! I managed to do it by creating a seprate .php page. Lastly, is it possible to do it so when they click the print button on "viewsjobs.php" it has a <a href="jobs.php?={$id}"> So it takes me to the document I want to print? Thanks.

Comment: yeah it is almost what you wrote: `<a href="jobs.php?id=<?php echo( $row['id'] ); ?>">Open this record</a>`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\services\viewjobs.php on line 75

I get this error when trying to run it?

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for you help!